# Orchard custom field not getting posted correctly

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

I have created a custom field in Orchard which is meant to just contain one field (GUID). So whenever it is added to a content type, it would show a new GUID in "Editor" template. This works fine, except when I submit the form which contains the content type, the form gets posted with a different GUID. On looking closely, I found the driver of the field for Editor (POST) does not updates the viewModel for the field.

Any suggestion or tips to debug ?

Here are some lines of my code

```
protected override DriverResult Display(
            ContentPart part, Fields.UniqueIDField field,
            string displayType, dynamic shapeHelper)
        {

            return ContentShape("Fields_String", // this is just a key in the Shape Table
                 GetDifferentiator(field, part),
                 () =>
                 {
                     var settings = field.PartFieldDefinition.Settings.GetModel<UniqueIdFieldSettings>();
                     var value = field.Id;


                     var viewModel = new UniqueIdFieldViewModel
                     {
                         Id = value
                     };

                     return shapeHelper.Fields_String( // this is the actual Shape which will be resolved (Fields/DateTime.cshtml)
                         Model: viewModel);
                 }
             );
        }

        protected override DriverResult Editor(ContentPart part,
                                               Fields.UniqueIDField field,
                                               dynamic shapeHelper)
        {

            var settings = field.PartFieldDefinition.Settings
                                .GetModel<UniqueIdFieldSettings>();
            var value = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            field.Id = value;

            var viewModel = new UniqueIdFieldViewModel
            {
                Id = value,
            };

            return ContentShape("Fields_String_Edit",
                () => shapeHelper.EditorTemplate(
                          TemplateName: TemplateName,
                          Model: viewModel,
                          Prefix: GetPrefix(field, part)));
        }

        protected override DriverResult Editor(ContentPart part,
                                               Fields.UniqueIDField field,
                                               IUpdateModel updater,
                                               dynamic shapeHelper)
        {

            var viewModel = new UniqueIdFieldViewModel();         
            if (updater.TryUpdateModel(viewModel,
                                       GetPrefix(field, part), null, null))
            {
                field.Id = viewModel.Id;
            }

            return Editor(part, field, shapeHelper);
        }
```

Comment: But you *are* resetting the value every time in the editor method.

Comment: I am getting new GUID in Editor-GET method and updating the model in Editor-POST. Can you suggest me the right way.

Comment: Check the edit template for the field.

Comment: You have got to have noticed that the POST method calls the GET method.

Comment: Thanks @BertrandLeRoy. Problem fixed. There were 2 issues a) Like you have pointed, the GET method resets everytime. I modified it by adding  null check for field value. b) The viewModel was not getting updated after POSTING because the edit template showed Id in a LABEL whose value was not getting POSTED. (modified to readonly textbox). How do I mark this question closed ?

Comment: I'll copy my suggestion as an answer, then you can accept is as an answer. No need to close anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are resetting the value every time in the GET editor method, which is called by the POST editor method every time at the end of its own execution. Only set to a new value if there isn't one already.